# The Login is from an untrusted domain - domain setup with computer level login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, security, authentication

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database I'm attempting to connect to using ADO.NET using integrated security in the connection string.

The database resides on a 64-bit Windows Server 2003 machine. The client is a 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise machine.

The specific error I receive from SQL Server is:

> The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

The computer is added as a windows account on the SQL Server as `DOMAIN.edu\ComputerName$` and has been granted full permissions on the target database.

Both the server and client are part of the same active directory domain. The computers can communicate with each other over remote desktop. The client machine can see network shares on the server machine, so I don't think network connectivity is a problem.

I didn't have a problem with this setup when the SQL Server 2008 R2 database was residing on a 64-bit Windows XP Professional machine and the client was the same machine.

What else can I verify or modify to make my current setup work for machine level authentication?

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of an AD question than a SQL question, but...

Whom is the application running as, and what are you trying to do?

By specifying that DOMAIN\computername$ has full permissions, you're implying that LocalSystem (NT Authority\System) or NetworkService is the account that will be running that process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28VS.85%29.aspx

(It's usually recommended to use a service account, or grant permissions to individual logins.)

If you've specified that the process is running as LocalService instead, that does not pass machine credentials.